# @Cacheable throws error Null key returned for cache operation

Tags: spring-boot, redis

**Update:**

tried `key="#p0"` , does not work

Trying to implement Redis with spring boot to cache my products, but I faced the problem, appreciate for any help

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?)**

**Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {

        List<Product> products = productService.findAll();
     
        return ResponseEntity.ok(products);
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
@Cacheable(value = "product", key = "#productId")
public List<Product> findAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
}
```

**@EnableCaching** annotation has also been put in the main class

Answer (score 3):

The value of `key` should match the name of one of the arguments to the method annotated with `@Cacheable`, findAll. As findAll has no arguments there is nothing to use as a key.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key

---

A simple way to "cache" all the products in memory is just to store the result from the first call to `productRepository.findAll()` in an instance variable.

```java
class ProductService {
  
  private List<Product> productCache;

  public List<Product> findAll() {
    if (productCache == null) {
      productCache = productRepository.findAll();
    }
    return productCache;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To fill your `product` cache with your `List<Product>` from the repository you could invoke the `CacheManager` programmatically:

```java
@Autowired CacheManager cacheManager;

public List<Product> findAll() {
    List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
    for (Product product : products) {
        cacheManager.getCache("product").put(product.getProductId(), product);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in **key** has to be one of the parameters of the method on which you've used the **cacheable** annotation.

One you thing you can do is to pass the value of **productId** when calling the **findAll** method.

The error simply means you're using a **null** value as your key. Redis doesn't allow this